# Azure DevOps build pipelines fail when another build is already running

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

When using Azure DevOps I notice that occasionally my pull request builds will fail. After some tracking down I noticed that this is only happening when another build is already running.

It seems that the reason is that the files in the output for the build (exe, dll, note_modules, etc.) will be locked so when another build is started the new build will fail until the currently running one is finished, then I will have to manually re-queue the build again.

I am not very familiar with Azure DevOps pipelines since we recently migrated to this platform and also not sure of the best way to fix this issue. The sln's being built include .NET Framework, .NET Core, TypeScript, and Node.js if that helps at all.

I would love to post the logs and current configuration, but due to company policy I'm not allowed to... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps build pipelines fail when another build is already running

You could try to use/add a **Capability**, like `Agent.Name` to that two specific build agents then in the build definition you put that capability as a **Demands**.

As stated here:

[How to send TFS build to a specific agent or server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericparvin/how-to-send-tfs-build-to-a-specific-agent-or-server)

The Capabilities of the agent:

```
Project Settings->Agent pools->Your agent pool-> Agents->Agent->Capabilities
```

The Demands of the build pipeline:

```
Options-> Demands:
```

[image]

In this case, when a pipeline is running in this particular agent, another new build will be in pending state until the current build is completed.